# AdonisJS Socket.IO JWT authentication

Tags: socket.io, jwt, adonis.js

How can you define the auth provider? Now every time the auth variable is undefined in the playerLogin method.

I'm are using Adonis v4.1

The code:
start/socket.js

```js
const Server = use('Server')
const io = use('socket.io')(Server.getInstance())

// Define controllers here
// Example: const WSController = use('App/Controllers/Http/ChatController')
const AuthenticateController = use('App/Controllers/Http/AuthenticateController');

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
  // Define here the controller methods
  // Example: WSController.goMessage(socket, io)
  AuthenticateController.playerLogin(socket, io);
  AuthenticateController.playerRegister(socket, io);
})
```

AuthenticateController.js

```js
const Hash = use('Hash')
const User = use('App/Models/User')

class AuthenticateController {
    static playerLogin(socket, io, {auth}) {
        socket.on('playerLogin', async (data) => {
            console.log('WORKS')
            if (await auth.attempt(data.email, data.password)) {
                let user = await User.findBy('email', data.email)
                let accessToken = await auth.generate(user)
                socket.emit('sendPlayerToken', { token: accessToken });
            } else {
                socket.emit('sendPlayerToken', { token: 'Credentials are incorrect' });
            }
        });
    }

    static playerRegister(socket, io) {
        socket.on('playerRegister', async (data) => {
            const safePassword = await Hash.make(data.password)
            const user = new User()
            user.username = data.username
            user.email = data.email
            user.password = safePassword
            await user.save()
            socket.emit('sendPlayerRegister', { success: true });
        });
    }
}
```

Kind regards,

Corné

Answer (score 0):

As this discussion bellow:

https://github.com/adonisjs/core/discussions/2051?sort=new#discussioncomment-274111

You can use the API guard and authenticate using the code from the answer of M4gie.

You only need to install the crypto package with `yarn add crypto` and if you don't want to create the object to display the socket errors, just turn it into a string: `throw new Error('SocketErrors:MissingParameter')`.